# How to get model in django in updateView

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
class PbsObjectUpdate(UpdateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        model_name = self.model.__name__
```

I can get the model inside any function by using

```
self.model.__name__
```

But how can get that outside the function and just below the class i.e

```
class PbsObjectUpdate(UpdateView):
      model_name = model.__name__
```

because i don't ahve self in that part

Comment: you can't, if you put it just below the class, it is a class variable. a class variable knows nothing about your instance variable(start with self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a getter:

```
class PbsObjectUpdate(UpdateView):
    @property
    def model_name(self):
        return self.model.__name__
```

Now you can use `PbsObjectUpdate().model_name`